# Xcode use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, identifier

I am new to coding and had some basic knowledge but i am building out my first app from a tutorial and have a issue i can't figure out and after a few days of looking figured i would just ask. I get an error in my implementation file when initializing the object in the view did load.
It says use of undeclared identifier. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my view controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"





@implementation ViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"titleLabel.text = %@", self.titleLabel.text);

    self.bandObject = [[BandObject alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.bandObject.name = self.nameTextField.text;
    [self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.bandObject.name =self.nameTextField.text;
    [self saveBandObject];
    [self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.saveNotesButton.enabled = YES;
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.bandObject.notes = self.notesTextView.text;
    [self.notesTextView resignFirstResponder];
    self.saveNotesButton.enabled = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)saveNotesButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    [self textViewShouldEndEditing:self.notesTextView];
}

- (IBAction)ratingStepperValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.ratingValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.ratingStepper.value];
    self.bandObject.rating = (int)self.ratingStepper.value;
}


- (IBAction)tourStatusSegmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.bandObject.touringStatus = self.touringStatusSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
}

- (IBAction)haveSeenLiveSwitchValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.bandObject.haveSeenLive = self.haveSeenLiveSwitch.on;
}

@end
```

and here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WBABand.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) WBABand *bandObject;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView *notesTextView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *saveNotesButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIStepper *ratingStepper;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ratingValueLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *touringStatusSegmentedControl;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch *haveSeenLiveSwitch;

- (IBAction)saveNotesButtonTouched:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ratingStepperValueChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)tourStatusSegmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)haveSeenLiveSwitchValueChanged:(id)sender;



@end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have an object in your .h called `WBABand`. And in your .m your are initializing a `BandObject` which does not exists.

Change this `[[BandObject alloc] init];`

to this `[[WBABand alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

When you run into an issue, please try to narrow it down to the shortest code block possible to reproduce. At the very least, you should be pointing out the line that shows the error so that contributors can help you easier.

---

You are trying to instantiate an instance of `BandObject`, but the class you should be trying to instantiate is `WBABand`.

```
self.bandObject = [[WBABand alloc] init];
```